# django user login after successful user creation failed

Tags: python, django, view, authentication

I have form :

```
class GeneralUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'duplicate_username': ("This Username already exists."),
    'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
}
username = forms.RegexField(label=("Username"), max_length=30,
    regex=r'^[\w.+-]+$',
    help_text=("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                "/./+/-/_ only."),
    error_messages={
        'invalid': ("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                     "./+/-/_ characters.")}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input username'}))
password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password",
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input username'}))
password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input username'}),
    help_text=("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input username'}))
#gender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'input username'}))
date_of_birth = forms.CharField(label=("Date of birth"),
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input username', "placeholder": "YYYY-MM-DD"}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GeneralUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call to ModelForm constructor
    self.fields['gender'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width:190px; height:40px; font-family:arial; border:1px solid #CCC;'
class Meta:
    model = GeneralUser
    fields = ("username", "email", "gender", "date_of_birth")
def clean_username(self):
    # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
    # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    try:
        User._default_manager.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username
    raise forms.ValidationError(
        self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
        code='duplicate_username',
    )
def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(GeneralUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

and I have view for creating user:

```
class GeneralUserCreateView(CreateView):

form_class = GeneralUserCreationForm
template_name = "general_user.html"

def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    user = GeneralUser()
    user.username = form.clean_username()
    user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    user.password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
    user.gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
    user.date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_general_user = True
    user.save()
    title = "Welcome to something"
    content = "Thank you for using our system."
    send_mail(title, content, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [user.email], fail_silently=True)

    return redirect("home_question")
```

The user is created successfully. When I see from admin side user is created. But when I login it says username and password didnt match.

But when I create a user from admin and login it is logged in without any errors.. I dont know whats wrong. I am using custom user model.

In admin side I am making user is_active and is_general_user to true. I think if the user created from admin can log in then the user created from view should also log in.

Whats wrong in here ?? Where am I making mistake ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly overridden the form's save method to set the hashed password via `user.set_password()`. But you never call that save from your view: instead, you instantiate a GeneralUser directly in the view's `form_valid` method, and there you set the password directly from cleaned_data, so it is not hashed.

Remove that instantiation from the view, and call the super method (which calls `form.save()`) instead:

```
def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(GeneralUserCreateView, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
    user = self.object
    title = "Welcome to something"
    content = "Thank you for using our system."
    send_mail(title, content, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [user.email], fail_silently=True)
    return response
```

Comment: Why not do that in the form save method?